# python stop when pyglet.app.run() applied

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm a beginner.
I tried to show some pictures by pyglet and it works will.
But the whole program stopped after the picture showed in window.
The main code is like

```
str="test"

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
print(str)
```

The code is simplified as the program's concept.
The issue is the code after pyglet.app.run() cannot be run.
Is there any way to solve this issue? And I also want to keep the picture window stay.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyglet has its own internal loop determined by `pyglet.app.run()`. So all the code present later is not executed unless you exit the loop. If you want to insert new things, you must either use Pyglet's default functions, or create new functions that are called in the Pyglet loop.

Comment: So, is that means I cannot reconnect to the loop and change the window content if I exit the loop right?

Comment: The only way to perform something outside the loop is to call up functions or classes in the Pyglet cycle. But going out and coming back can not be done. Once you exit the loop, either terminate the script, or start a new cycle.

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete explanation about loops [here](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/time.html#guide-calling-functions-periodically) and functions which you can use pyglet in, you'd better use pyglet in a function.

You can also use `pyglet.app.event_loop.sleep(delay)` instead of `pyglet.app.run()` in which delay is some time provided for pyglet to do his job.

Comment: If I use pyglet.app.event_loop.sleep(delay), the on_draw is not called and nothing is displayed in the window. How to solve this?